# Software Updater - Not all updates can be installed

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I try to update my system, i get the following error message:

> Software Updater - Not all updates can be installed

I googled and some suggested to fix the broken packages using `sudo apt-get install -f`. But that did not work for me.

When I use `apt-get upgrade` this is the message I receive:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages have been kept back:
  gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 librhythmbox-core8 libtotem-plparser18 libva1
  libvlc5 libvncserver0 linux-generic-lts-utopic
  linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic linux-image-generic-lts-utopic rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder
  rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune rhythmbox-plugins smplayer smplayer-themes totem
  totem-common totem-mozilla totem-plugins vlc vlc-data vlc-nox
  vlc-plugin-libde265 vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse
The following packages will be upgraded:
  google-chrome-stable mkvtoolnix mkvtoolnix-gui
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
Need to get 53.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 6,539 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
```

What i don't get is why the linux kernel image has the name `linux-image-generic-lts-utopic`(Why does it contain the word `utopic`, even though the code name is `trusty`)? I also looked at the `/etc/apt/sources.list`. There is no occurrence of the word `utopic` in it.

### Things I have tried

1. Fix Broken Packages using `apt-get install -f`
2. The commands :
   `apt-get autoremove && apt-get clean && apt-get update`

What can i do to make the System Updater to work normal? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: @snoop No. I did not try with `dist-upgrade`. Let me check with it.

Comment: Maybe you accidentally added repositories from Utopic Unicorn? Check your software repositories to see if that is the case. They should only show `trusty` and not `utopic`

Comment: @Rewarp Like i mentioned in the question, there is no occurrence of the word utopic in sources.list file.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The problem got solved after running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

## What does this do?

From `apt-get` man page:

> `dist-upgrade` in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions 
>   of packages; `apt-get` has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and
>   it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the
>   expense of less important ones if necessary. The `dist-upgrade`
>   command may therefore remove some packages.

Comment: indeed! Worth mentioning that it does not upgrade ubuntu, but only fixes dependencies of installed applications. thanks

Comment: This helped, thank you. I had a setting set `psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=1` which prevented upgrades. Commenting it out and running `sudo apt-get install -f` solved the problem.

Comment: fantastic !!!!!

Comment: No idea why this is not made clearer what this does and why it not offered as part of the upgrade to 20.04 but rather the error message of this OP will show after the upgrade ...

Comment: Had the same problem and used this solution. However it killed my MySQL installation and I had to re-install.

Comment: Thank you! Helped me!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get past this issue, as per a post elsewhere on the net (forget where), by using Synaptic to upgrade my packages. Afterwards, the software updater was no longer complaining, and could fetch/install the updates since then.

Answer (score 0):

I would do further checks in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or via `y-ppa-manager` or via `Software and Updates` temporarily uncheck some repos or sources which temporarily may contain some newer packages with broken dependencies or assign the version of Your Ubuntu as each source repo extension to be sure install e.g. only 'trusty' not 'utopic' version. Usually this is kind of issue occured for some time if personal PPAs are in use and then is fixed by updated software makers either on official Ubuntu side or software provider. If the breakening seems permanent then the solution mentioned above may be needed. Maybe You use custom Rhythmbox or Vlc PPAs?
Surely `Synaptic` seemes in many ocassions still more clear and transparent.

Answer (score -1):

I have used this command and it solved my issue:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```